# Application not running on real Android device

Tags: android, android-emulator, adt, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-2.3

I tried a lot of time running my app in my cell Samsung Galaxy S3 but always getting the same thing

```
[2014-04-14 20:11:14 - BridgeText] Android Launch!
[2014-04-14 20:11:14 - BridgeText] adb is running normally.
[2014-04-14 20:11:14 - BridgeText] Performing com.bridge.text.ChatNameActivity activity launch
[2014-04-14 20:11:14 - BridgeText] No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.
```

Also tried to reset adb but getting following error:

```
[2014-04-14 20:15:22 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2014-04-14 20:15:23 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

my device's usb debugging mode is enabled and my device's android version is 4.3 and I also have updated my API. However I also show my AndroidManifest file if it makes it easy to understand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bridge.text"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.bridge.text.ChatNameActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.bridge.text.TextActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_messages_title"
            android:parentActivityName="com.bridge.text.ChatNameActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.bridge.text.ChatNameActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
 <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your device recognized if you run 'adb devices' at the command line?

Comment: no its not even showing there

Comment: Which host OS are you using?

Comment: My system's OS is Windows 8, however I tried it in my friend's laptop as well. He is having Windows 7, but same is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to manually enter a value in your adb_usb.ini file. On Windows, that can be done with:

```
echo 0xYYYY >> "%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini"
```

where YYYY is the 4-digit Vendor ID for your device. I believe that's '04e8' for Samsung devices.

You'll need to then restart ADB with:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

Several known Android vendor IDs are at the bottom of this [page](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). And [here's](http://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/) a more complete list of USB IDs.

Comment: how can I find the vendor ID of my device.

Comment: I added a link in the answer. Did you get it to work?